# Use custom username with onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

First, I register my customer with:

```js
const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        // The username will be created here
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(username)
          .collection("profile")
          .doc(username)
          .set({
            username: username,
          });
        // it successfully created a new user with email and password
        if (auth) {
          history.push("/dashboard");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

Then, in my `App.js` I dispatch `SET_USER` and I try to set my `user` value in my reducer to `username` that was set in my database.

```js
function App() {
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  useEffect(() => {
    // will only run once when the app component loads...

    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("THE USER IS >>> ", authUser);

      if (authUser) {
        // the user just logged in / the user was logged in

        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });
      } else {
        // the user is logged out
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

However, I am unsure how I should pull the username from firebase and dispatch it as the `user` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a custom property you should link it to the provided by Firebase:
You may use the `email` or `displayName` the  as the descriptor.

```
db.collection("users")
 .doc(email)
 .collection("profile")
 .doc(email)
 .set({
  username: username,
 });
```

This way you can retrieve the username based on the email.